# Elastic search not_analyzed fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a loginid field in my elastic search Database which contain user email ids. I want to write a search query to list all occurrence of a particular mail client (eg gmail.com, yahoo.com etc).

I have managed to write a search query with exact match of an email id

```
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "loginid": "dibeesh@amt.in"
      }
   }
}
```

By executing above query i will get an exact match. My requirement is to match all email ids ends with '@amt.in'. 
loginid is a non_analyzed field in my elastic search db ie

```
"loginid": {
  "type": "string",
   "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

**I have also tried parse_prefix query**

```
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "loginid": {
            "query": "dibeesh@amt.in",
            "type": "phrase_prefix"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But no luck to get my desired result. Please help me to find a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "regexp":{
        "loginid": "*@amt.in"
    }
}
```

use the elastic search regular expression query to achieve this.